# I need help understanding The Integral Test for the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n(\ln n-1)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For the following Series I have to show that the series qualifies for The Integral Test, then use it to determine if the series converges or diverges.
[image: The series that i apply the integral test]

here's my work where I apply the Integral Test, but I did this without knowing if it qualifies. 
[image: I applied the Integral test here]
To show if the series qualifies for the test I have to show 3 things:
that f(x) is continuous, positive and decreasing. This is where I am stuck, how do I show these 3 things.
[image: The Integral Test]
After all the help and hints I ended up with the following:
[image: Final work]
[image: final work2]

Comment: It is better to start at $2$, or later. Note that our sequence is term by term bigger than $\frac{1}{n\log n}$. Note also that $\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x\ln x}\,dx$ diverges. (It is clear I think that $\frac{1}{x\ln x}$ is decreasing.)   I have difficulty reading the picture. What you did looks roughly OK, except that you must not start at $1$. Why not start at $3$, nice and safe, because then the function is decreasing.

Comment: Hmm yea I noticed that starting at 1 will cause some problems. and i just realized that I put ln(-1) is 0 and that is wrong. Also don't I need to start at 1 since that is where it says to start? n=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $f(x)$ qualifies (i.e., satisfies the hypotheses of the integral test), we need to show that $f(x)$ is continuous, positive, and decreasing.  Note that the textbook says $[1,\infty)$.  But it's ok for us to use $[3,\infty)$.  Actually, using 1 won't even work because $f(1) < 0$.  Similarly, $f(2) < 0$.

If you're wondering why it's OK to start at 3 when the textbook says $[1,\infty)$, the reason is that we really only care what happens as $x$ (or $n$, or whatever variable name we're using) tends to $\infty$.  Therefore it doesn't matter where we start, whether it's 1, or 2, or 3, or 475 million, etc.  I feel like this is a very important point and it saddens me that many textbooks and instructors don't emphasize it.  Sigh.

Anyway, it's pretty clear that $f(x)$ is continuous and positive on $[3,\infty)$.  To show that it's decreasing, we just need to show $f'(x) < 0$ for $x \ge 3$.  This is also pretty straightforward but does involve some calculus/algebra.

More information:

I'd be careful about how you show your work.  For improper integrals, the *proper* (sorry) way to do it is to take limits.  That is, do this instead:
$$ \int_3^{+\infty} \frac{1}{t-1} \, dt = \lim_{B \to +\infty} \int_3^B \frac{1}{t-1} \, dt =  \lim_{B \to +\infty} \left(\ln|t-1| \bigg|_3^B\right) = \cdots $$

Also, with definite integrals there is no need to "undo" your $t$-substitution.  It just creates extra and unneeded work.

Comment: Thank you for explaining to me that we don't care at what n starts, that what matters is what eventually happens in the future as n goes to infinity. okay I will try do the derivative right now to show it is decreasing. So when doing the integral I will now use 3 instead of 1 and i can put a note on the side why I am using 3, or is that not necessary to put a note why? I will take into consideration what you noted at the end. thank you for your help.

Comment: I would say it isn't necessary to explain why you're starting at $3$ but it isn't a bad idea.  Actually it'd probably just be enough to say that $f(x)$ is continuous and positive for $x \ge 3$.

Comment: I redid the whole thing again, and i attached it to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure described in the post is largely right. But there is trouble at the beginning, because $\frac{1}{x(\ln x-1)}$ is not strictly decreasing.  Also, the integration runs into trouble because our function is initially negative.

This can all be fixed by noting that a well defined series $a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots$ converges if and only, for example, the series $a_7+a_8+a_9+\cdots$ converges. To test for convergence/divergence, we can choose where to start summing from. Only the "tail behaviour" matters.

In our case, consider the series $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\ln n-1)}$. For $x\ge 3$,  $\ln x -1$ is positive. The function $x(\ln x-1)$ is positive and increasing in the interval $[3,\infty)$, so its reciprocal is decreasing.  We can, using your calculation, show that $\int_3^\infty \frac{dx}{x(\ln x-1)}$ diverges, and therefore by the integral test our series diverges.

*Remark:* It really makes no difference, but I probably would have observed that for $n\ge 3$ our series is term by term bigger than $\frac{1}{n\ln n}$.  Then I would have used the divergence of $\int_3^\infty \frac{dx}{x\ln x}$ to prove the divergence of our original series.